# MySQL - Split the column in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

How can I split a column into multiple columns so that each column contain the values for different ID?

```
select ID, Value from table1

ID     Value
==========
1    test1
1    test2
2    test3
2    test4
2    test5
2    test6
```

I want the resultset split in multiple parts based on the ID column. Each ID need to have different column

```html
ID   Value     ID   Value
==========================
1    test1     2    test3 
1    test2     2    test4 
               2    test5
               2    test6
```

Comment: It makes little sense to do it in SQL. SQL should give you the relations, and shouldn't deal with presentation.

Comment: Thanks Amadan. I changed the question. Can you please check it?

Comment: Not much better, I'm afraid. The correct answer to "how to securely attach an anteater to a banana using a voltmeter" is "why would you want to do that?" This is almost certainly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).